# c# WPF - SetZIndex UserControl issue

Tags: c#, wpf, z-index

**Issue**: I get an exception `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'` when I call the `Canvas.SetZIndex()` function.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** I have 2 UserControls stacked on top of each other in my WPF application. After one button click I would like to bring one to the front and bring the old UserControl the back using `SetZIndex()`.

**My code in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // Innitiate the variable
    public UserControl currentUserControl;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // My 2 UserControls that are defined in MainWindow.xaml
        // <local:UserControl1 x:Name="homeControl" Margin="160,41,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="99"/>
        // <local:ProfileUserControl x:Name="profileControl" Margin="160,41,0,0"/>

        // Define current UserControl that is in front
        UserControl currentUserControl = homeControl; // <-- DEFINED VARIABLE
    }






    // Custom function to bring a UserControl in front
    public void BringToFront(UserControl switchTo)
    {
        // bring new UserControl to front
        Canvas.SetZIndex(switchTo, 99);

        // bring "old" UserControl to back
        Canvas.SetZIndex(currentUserControl, 0); // <---- PROBLEM HERE

        // define the UserControl we just brought to front as the current UserControl that is in front
        currentUserControl = switchTo;
    }
}
```

The problem here seems to be the `currentUserControl` variable. It seems to be empty(null) whenever I call it inside the `BringToFront()` function.

I don't understand how though, I made sure to fill it with `homeControl` at the start of the script..

**Am I missing something here?**

Comment: `UserControl currentUserControl = homeControl;` creates local variable with name `currentUserControl`. It's not related to field `currentUserControl`, so that field is always null. Change to `this.currentUserControl = homeControl;`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much @Evk